# awk equivalent of cut -f2-

Tags: shell, awk

That is, what is the suggested work around of extracting fields after Nth?
I can't find any shortcut in awk to do this.

What is the most efficient and easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at regexes? My awk-fu is weak, but in Perl, I'd do `m/(?:[^@]+)@(.*)/; $foo = $3;` for delimiter `@`. The trick is to use `(?:[^@]+)@` to skip over the initial fields.

Comment: WOW Perl is far beyond my understanding... that's why I'm still sticking in awk :)

Comment: It's definitely worth your effect to learn extended POSIX regexes.

Comment: If my posting answered you question, please accept the answer by clicking the little green hook beneath the number of upvotes in the upper left corner.

Comment: Recently I came across this problem again, I need to preserve **exactly** what I have(multiple space. etc) after certain column. I realized that the regex in sub() can be generated dynamicaly:  `awk -vPOS=XXX '{ ma=" *"; for (i=1;i<=POS;i++){ ma=ma$i" *";}; sub(ma, "", $0); print $0;}'` Kinda resource-consuming though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use something like this:

```
awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" ";printf "\n"}' file
```

EDIT:

For a generic version use:

```
/home/sirch> echo 1:2:3:4:5 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)a=(a)?a OFS $i:$i;print a;a=""}'
2:3:4:5
/home/sirch> echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)a=(a)?a OFS $i:$i;print a;a=""}'
2,3,4,5
/home/sirch> echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)a=(a)?a OFS $i:$i;print a;a=""}'
3,4,5
/home/sirch> echo 1,2,3,4,5 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for (i=3;i<=4;i++)a=(a)?a OFS $i:$i;print a;a=""}'
3,4
```

FS sets the input field separator, OFS sets the output field separator.
If you want to use ":" e. g. as delimiter, set FS and OFS to ":".
You can use regexp as delimiters, too.

EDIT 2:

If you are interested in a complete implementation of cut in awk, take a look here:

http://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/html_node/Cut-Program.html

HTH Chris

Comment: Logical and I can't think of any other work-around of better performance. Thank you!

Comment: Of course not. If you want to use another delimiter, specify it with FS="foobar", or -F.

Answer (score 0):

Not as nice as Chris's solution but this would also print everything after the first field:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}' file
```

Comment: This isn't the same as cut; it will begin with a field separator.